# How can I open a Generic Inquiry screen with a record via BLC code?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I've got code in a BLC to open a Generic Inquiry screen with an associated GI name - but it seems to be missing something to fill in all the fields.  For example, this is what I get if I open the screen and navigate to a record manually:

[image]

And here is what I get when opening through code:

[image]

Here is the code I'm using to open the screen (where giName is a variable that contains the GI Name - "AM-Cost"):

```
GenericInquiryDesigner graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<GenericInquiryDesigner>();

GIDesign gid = PXSelect<GIDesign,                               
               Where<GIDesign.name, Equal<Required<GIDesign.name>>>>.Select(this, giName);
            
if (gid == null) return;

graph.Designs.Current = gid;

throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(graph, "View Entity")
{
      Mode = PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.NewWindow
};
```

I can't see anything else that I need to provide besides the GI Name.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select GIDesign, use GenericInquiryDesigner graph:

```
 GIDesign gid = PXSelect<GIDesign,
    Where<GIDesign.name, Equal<Required<GIDesign.name>>>>
    .Select(graph /* "this" was replaced here */, giName);
```

Comment: That did the trick - thanks mucn!!  ;D